# Multithread socket - Possible concurrent access

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, heap-memory, stack-memory

I may be wrong but it seems to me that on this code a global variable called `_buffer` is being assigned to a new object on the heap by multiple threads, so if a thread is trying to read data from it in a function after writing to it in a previous function, but in the meanwhile another thread has assigned this variable _buffer to another object on the heap, I'll get wrong data. Is this really happening or am I wrong? If it is, how do I fix?

```
public class SocketServer
{
    Socket _serverSocket;
    List<Socket> _clientSocket = new List<Socket>();
    byte[] _buffer;

    public SocketServer()
    {
        _serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    }

    public void Bind(int Port)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Setting up server...");
        _serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, Port));
    }

    public void Listen(int BackLog)
    {
        _serverSocket.Listen(BackLog);
    }

    public void Accept()
    {
        _serverSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, null);
    }

    private void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
    {
        Socket socket = _serverSocket.EndAccept(AR);
        _clientSocket.Add(socket);
        Console.WriteLine("Client Connected");
        _buffer = new byte[1024];
        socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, socket);
        Accept();
    }

    private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
    {
        Socket socket = AR.AsyncState as Socket;
        int bufferSize = socket.EndReceive(AR);

        string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(_buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        Console.WriteLine("Text Received: {0}", text);

        string response = string.Empty;

        if (text.ToLower() != "get time")
            response = $"\"{text}\" is a Invalid Request";
        else
            response = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();

        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response);
        socket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, SendCallback, socket);

        _buffer = new byte[1024];
        socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, socket);
    }

    private void SendCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
    {
        (AR.AsyncState as Socket).EndSend(AR);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [data race](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1d42da/race-conditions-in-threading-C-Sharp/) when multiple threads are involved, and at least one of them is a writer.

[`Socket`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket(v=vs.110).aspx) is thread-safe, but `SocketServer` **isn't**. You're writing to `_buffer` immediately before using it. This is most definitely a data race in a multithreaded scenario. You need a locking mechanism around every access to shared state.

There's no point in using a field for `_buffer` if you overwrite it immediately before passing it along. If you need one buffer to work with, assign it once at initialization time. To avoid changing it too much, you could implement it like this:

```
class SocketServer
{
    class Transaction
    {
        public readonly byte[] Data;
        public readonly Socket Socket;

        public Transaction(byte[] data, Socket socket)
        {
            Data = data;
            Socket = socket;
        }
    }

    private readonly object _syncObj = new object();
    private readonly List<Transaction> _received = new List<Transaction>();
    //...

    //...
    private void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
    {
        //...
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        socket.BeginReceive(
            buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None,
            ReceiveCallback, new Transaction(buffer, socket));
        //...
    }
    private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
    {
        Transaction trans = (Transaction)AR.AsyncState;
        Socket socket = trans.Socket;
        int bufferSize = socket.EndReceive(AR);
        lock (_syncObj) {
            _received.Add(trans);
        }
        //...
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        socket.BeginReceive(
            buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, 
            ReceiveCallback, new Transaction(buffer, socket));
    }
    //...

    // Call this to get all the received data. 
    // This will block ReceiveCallback until it completes.
    public byte[] GetReceivedData()
    {
        int totalSize = 0;
        lock (_syncObj) {
            for (int i = 0; i < _received.Length; i++) {
                totalSize += _received[i].Data.Length;
            }

            byte[] totalData = new byte[totalSize];
            int offset = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < _received.Length; i++) {
                byte[] blockData = _received[i].Data;
                Buffer.BlockCopy(blockData, 0, totalData, offset, blockData.Length);
                offset += blockData.Length;
            }
            _received.Clear();
            return totalData;
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could create a thread-safe implementation of `IList<ArraySegment<byte>>` and use the appropriate [overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3sah14d0(v=vs.110).aspx), but that's out of the scope of this answer.

On an unrelated note, your naming conventions are inconsistent. You're using underscore camel case for fields, a mixture of uppercase & pascal case for parameters, and camel case for local variables. Use whatever conventions you desire, but please be consistent. I suggest following the [general guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions).

Answer (score 2):

_buffer isn't thread-safe. I'd use a concurrent collection like ConcurrentBag instead of a plane byte array. That will guarantee thread-safety for you.
If you want to keep _buffer as an array, you would have to use appropriate Locks (e.g by using the lock keyword) to make sure multiple threads do not concurrently try to access _buffer.
More on ConcurrentBag: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779(v=vs.110).aspx